# How to remove '(not set)' false positives in Google Analytics traffic reports about DSpace

Tags: google-analytics, dspace

Google Analytics traffic reports for eCommons on DSpace have recently massively spiked false '(not set)' hits, so we're getting impossibly high hit numbers on web traffic. We can filter them out in the GA reports, but is there a way to configure something in eCommons, DSpace or GA to not register them in GA in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would be a good use of the filters, located under the View settings. I use these filters for ghost spam on all my properties, and you should be able to use them for your case.

It's not clear what field is showing up as `(not set)` in your case, but assuming it's one of the available filter fields in the drop down, you can build a filter that excludes all hits with a specific value.

[image]